# Applescript - Lock Finder selection

Tags: finder, applescript

I found scripts that lock a file w/ a specific path but none that lets me "lock the selected item/s in the Finder".

Could sb give me a hand with this?

Much appreciated.

Comment: What have you got so far? What worked, where did it fail?

Comment: Add those scripts (at LEAST!) to your question please.

Comment: Why is this question considered off-topic? It's about accessing a Finder feature using applescript. I glanced at the guidelines and didn't see any obvious discrepancy. While it could be better written, it seems on-topic to me, which is evidenced by the simple and succinct answer.

Comment: @Mockman, The question is not really off-topic per se. The reason is given in the paragraph below the off-topic line. Obviously this question was closed after I answered it and it was also marked as the accepted answer before it was closed. Which of course makes its closure even more ridiculous!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will set the `locked` *property* of selected *items* in **Finder** to *true*:

```applescript
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with thisItem in (get selection)
        set locked of thisItem to true
    end repeat
end tell
```

<sup>**NOTE:** The *filesystem* of the *container* has to support the `locked` *property* of the selected *items*.  As an example, an **ExFAT** volume does not support the `locked` *property* on *folders* but it does for *files*. Whereas on a **HFS+** or **APFS** volume it supports it for both *files* and *folders*.</sup>